# Parent class expecting var as T, child class gives var as child of T

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public class BaseUser
{
    protected virtual SyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

public class User : BaseUser
{
    protected override UserSyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new UserSyncLists(); } //Error: "Type must be SyncLists"
    }
}

public class EncryptedUser : BaseUser
{
    protected override EncryptedUserSyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new EncryptedUserSyncLists(); } //Error: "Type must be SyncLists"
    }
}
```

`UserSyncLists` and `EncryptedUserSyncLists` both extends `SyncLists`.

Is there any way to specify to expect children classes? Something along the lines of:

```
public class BaseUser
{
    protected virtual (Children of)SyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your override should NOT change the type which is returned. If the types are anyhow inherting SyncLists. In the end, the one who receives the SyncLists could check if it is of type UserSyncLists and convert it, but you have to keep the defined structure of your BaseClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you want to call the `SyncLists` property?

If, in another class, you want to consume a `BaseUser` without worrying what subtype it is, then it stands to reason that you don't want to worry about the subtype of `SyncLists`. In which case, this will suffice.

```
public class User : BaseUser
{
    protected override SyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new UserSyncLists(); }
    }
}
```

and the similar for `EncryptedUser`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing at the moment to avoid the error. But in this case, even if we return a `UserSyncLists`, its type is `SyncLists`. What if `UserSyncLists.customMethod()` is not defined in `SyncLists`?

Comment: You check it by unsing `var list = User.SyncLists as UserSyncLists; if (list != null) ...`

Comment: @ArthurRey Then you cast the return type as needed. Go look at [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx), it runs in to the same problem as you (`GetResponse()` returns a `WebResponse`). The example on that page shows the casting.

Comment: @ArthurRey There's little point overriding a virtual property if you can't deal with the result as its base type without casting it. Consider doing away with your base property and just keeping the two non-virtual properties.

Comment: @TimRogers The thing is I only those two different User classes for now, but I want it to be as generic as possible to create new User class without editing the BaseUser class.

Comment: @ArthurRey My proposal doesn't require you to edit the `BaseUser` class if you add a new sub-class. I'm just saying you don't need to override a virtual property because the type you want each property to return is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the return type as a generic parameter:

```
public class BaseUser<T> where T : SyncLists
{
    protected virtual T SyncLists
    {
        get { return default(T); }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public class User : BaseUser<UserSyncLists>
{
    protected override UserSyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new UserSyncLists(); }
    }
}
```

Note that if you only want to abstract away, you can always use the base `SyncList` and simply return a more derived type and simply cast each time you want to see if it is of a child object (although that can get cumbersome). Though if you are asking this, i'm assuming you want to deal directly with the child objects.

Also, as @Scot mentioned, this will make it harder to be using an `IEnumerable<BaseUser>`.

Comment: One drawback with this approach is you can't make a `IEnumerable<BaseUser>` anymore and have it contain both `User` and `EncryptedUser` items and use `item.SyncLists` in a foreach loop.

Comment: You're right. Didn't think about that. Though i didn't see the OP requiring that.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation of protected members overriding a base class it can't be done, you just have to cast inside the class that is calling `SyncLists`. However if you are in a similar situation with a interface and public members it can be done.

All you need to do is use a explicit interface implementation of the "more generic" version then have your own classes expose their specific versions.

```
public interface IUser
{
    SyncLists SyncLists { get; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    SyncLists IUser.SyncLists
    {
        get { return SyncLists; }
    }

    public UserSyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new UserSyncLists();}
    }
}

public class EncryptedUser : IUser
{
    SyncLists IUser.SyncLists
    {
        get { return SyncLists; }
    }

    public EncryptedUserSyncLists SyncLists
    {
        get { return new EncryptedUserSyncLists(); }
    }
}
```

This is the same pattern you normally implement when working with `IEnumerable<T>` to implement both `IEnumerator GetEnumorator()` and `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //....
    }
}
```